# How to import a dependency's .vue file

Tags: vue.js, npm, hadoop-yarn

I encountered this line of code in a vue project here https://github.com/InfinetyEs/Nova-Filemanager/blob/c6595c29e23cab01be6b7e37a069b13844397c91/resources/js/modules/Image.vue#L42:

```
import Viewer from 'v-viewer/src/component.vue';
```

I know from other examples that `v-viewer` is the dependency, so `src/component.vue` isn't part of this project. However, those other examples are only importing the dependency, i.e. `import Viewer from 'v-viewer'`.

The issue I'm facing is that `npm run dev` is complaining that it cannot find the dependency and I have practically 0 experience with vue.

What is the proper way to write the above so that it is pulling `component.vue` from the dependency `v-viewer`?

Thank you!

UPDATE: I wrote this `import { component } from 'v-viewer'` and it compiled. Appreciate if someone can confirm and explain if what I'm doing is correct.

Comment: The project relies on v-viewer internals, which is a dangerous thing to do because they aren't guaranteed to exist. This is the case here. There is loose version constraint, `"v-viewer": "^1.4.2"`, and src was removed in later versions. You can either fix it to be `"v-viewer": "1.4.2"`, or import and use it like `import { component as Viewer } from "v-viewer"`, the latter is preferable and this is what the docs show.

Comment: Thank you. Why not make it a reply to my question so that I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: Sure, hope you sorted this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project relies on `v-viewer` internals, which is a dangerous thing to do because they aren't guaranteed to exist.

This is the case here. There is loose version constraint, `"v-viewer": "^1.4.2"`, and `src` was removed in later versions. You can either fix it to be `"v-viewer": "1.4.2"`, or import and use it like shown in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-viewer#user-content-usage-of-component):

```
import { component as Viewer } from "v-viewer"
```

The latter solution is more preferable because this is the way the package was designed to be used without relying on its internals.